# GIT: Change where my new branch is originated from

Tags: git

I started a new branch off of `staging`. I'm 3-4 commits in, and realized I needed to branch off of `master` instead of `staging`.
How can I change my original branch but still keep my work/commits?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 7):

### Use [git rebase --onto](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

`git rebase --onto NEW_SOURCE_BRANCH FIRST_COMMIT_BEFORE_YOUR_WORK`

`NEW_SOURCE_BRANCH` is where you meant to be branched from

this will rewind your commits that are after `FIRST_COMMIT_BEFORE_YOUR_WORK` and then it will replay them onto `NEW_SOURCE_BRANCH` and then put you there at which point you can either create a new branch of this work or reset hard your old branch.

Note I would have said use `origin/master` as the `FIRST_COMMIT_BEFORE_YOUR_WORK` but it's likely that `master` isn't 'there' anymore; but it's trivial to find either way..

Comment: Great explanation and worked well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Easy method:

```
git log --oneline -4 #find all the commit hashes you want to get
git checkout origin/master
git checkout -b $newbranch
git cherry-pick $A $B $C $D
```

Your history is ABCD, as in your first commit is A, then B, etc.

Cherry pick the hashes you need from your staging branch. You are not going to be dynamically finding your changes today, as you only have 3-4 commits, copy the hashes, and apply the changes to your new branch.

---